# Angular2 - Typing subscribed data to interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that is subscribing to data from a service. This service returns a `BehaviorSubject` that I can subscribe to. In the data object returned, there are several arrays which make up the Label/Value of my dropdowns.

I am trying to type cast each of those arrays to their own interface and then use them within my UI.

**Component:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MassEmpService } from '../shared';
import { Segments } from '../definitions';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-transition',
    templateUrl: './transition.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./transition.component.css']
})
export class TransitionComponent implements OnInit {

    effectiveStartDate: string;
    error: string;
    transitionFields: any[];
    fieldsLoaded = false;
    transitionForm: FormGroup;
    segments: Segments[] = [];

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private _massEmpService: MassEmpService
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createForm();
    }

    // Generate the form
    createForm() {

        // Create our form for the transition options
        this.transitionForm = this.fb.group({
            changeType: ['', Validators.required],
            effectiveStartDate: ['', Validators.required],
            effectiveEndDate: [''],
            hierarchy: ['-1'],
            segment: ['-1'],
            supervisor: ['-1'],
            budgetMarket: ['-1'],
            incentivePlan: ['-1'],
            role: ['-1'],
            primaryLanguage: ['-1'],
            secondaryLanguage: ['-1'],
        });

        // Get our form data to populate
        this.fetchFieldData();
    }

    // Fetch the data from our service and set our array to its value received
    fetchFieldData() {

        this._massEmpService.transitionFields.subscribe((results) => {
            this.segments = results.segments.options;
        });

        this._massEmpService.fetchTransitionFields('');
    }

}
```

**Interface:**

```
export interface Segments {
    SegmentID: number;
    SegmentName: string;
}
```

**Service:**

```
public transitionFields: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

/**
 * Return an object of the input field data to render the drop-downs.
 * If provided a date, use this to find inputs that will either be
 * available or removed on that date.
 *
 * @param {any} effectiveStartDate
 * @returns
 * @memberof MassEmpService
 */
fetchTransitionFields(effectiveStartDate) {
    return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchTransitionFields', { "effectiveStartDate": effectiveStartDate }, { "headers": this.headers })
        .map((result: Response) => result.json())
        .subscribe((results) => this.transitionFields.next(results.data));
};
```

**Data Object:**

This:

```
this._massEmpService.transitionFields.subscribe((results) => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Returns:

[image]

**My HTML:**

```
<select name="segment" id="segment" formControlName="segment" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option value="-1" selected="selected">No Segment Change</option>
  <option *ngFor="let s of segments" value="{{ s.SegmentID }}">{{ s.SegmentName }}</option>
</select>
```

**The Issue:**

In my component, it is throwing an undefined error due to the subscription not having the data at the time it is trying to assign it to the var. I believe there is something wrong with the way I am subscribing to this data thats not allowing me to assign this data. Specifically, it is saying that `segments` is undefined.

The reason I am trying to assign `segments` directly from the results object is because I want to be able to `type` it. There will be many more drop-downs that I define once I figure out this issue as well.

My end goal in this is that each of the arrays in the object I received will be `typed` out and have their own interface. I would prefer to only have to make the one call to the service that gets the object of data and then from there, assigns it to its own individual objects like I am trying to do with the `segments`.

Many people have pointed out that its an `async` issue due to the subscription not having the data at the time I am assigning it. I am just not sure how to go about resolving that in my current setup.

I have tried an `async pipe`, `ngIf`, and `?.` from the suggestions and it still results in the undefined error.

Comment: What is the HTML code? where is it throwing `undefined` error?

Comment: just do this skillSets: SkillSets[] = [];. It will work.

Comment: Can you provide your template?

Comment: @brijmcq - Added the select input I am trying to render.

Comment: @SBB posted my answer. hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the SkillSets array

```
SkillSets[] = [];
```

Comment: I tried this and it resulted with the same undefined error unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Because your data are being retrieved asynchronously, the HTML doesnt get the data and hence your `skillsets` will be null when the component is constructed. There are a few way to handle this.

**Method 1** : Use an `async` pipe in your html:

```
<select name="skillset" id="skillset" formControlName="skillSet" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">No SkillSet Change</option>
    <option *ngFor="let s of skillSets | async" value="{{ s.SkillSetID }}">{{ s.SkillSetName }}</option>
</select>
```

**Method 2**: Use Elvis Operator `?.`

```
<select name="skillset" id="skillset" formControlName="skillSet" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">No SkillSet Change</option>
    <option *ngFor="let s of skillSets" value="{{ s?.SkillSetID }}">{{ s?.SkillSetName }}</option>
</select>
```

**Method 3**: Use `*ngIf`:

```
<select *ngIf="skillSets" name="skillset" id="skillset" formControlName="skillSet" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">No SkillSet Change</option>
    <option *ngFor="let s of skillSets" value="{{ s.SkillSetID }}">{{ s.SkillSetName }}</option>
</select>
```

#### Edit:

You still need to initialize your `skillsets` in your constructor. Typescript cannot magically know your default value `Skillsets`.

```
constructor(){
    this.skillSets = [];
}
```

Or you can do it at your property level:

```
skillSets: SkillSets[] = []; //initialize to empty array.
```

You can also typecast it in your response, if you want, using `as`:

```
export class DemoComponent {
    effectiveStartDate: string;
    error: string;
    transitionFields: any[];
    fieldsLoaded = false;
    transitionForm: FormGroup;
    skillSets: SkillSets[];

    constructor(){
        this.skillSets = [];
    }
    // Fetch the data from our service and set our array to its value received
    fetchFieldData() {

        this._massEmpService.transitionFields.subscribe((results) => {
            this.transitionFields = results;
            this.skillSets = results.segments.options as SkillSets[];
        });

        this._massEmpService.fetchTransitionFields('');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried these three options in my HTML above and they didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I must have an issue with the subscribe portion as neither of the 3 blocks of code work. They are all generating the undefined error. The data gets logged correctly though if i comment out the line thats trying to access the object so I know its named correctly.

Comment: @SBB, remember you still need to initialize whateveryour property, in your constructor, as suggested by other answers.

Comment: I copied your examples verbatim with no luck :/ - I appreciate the responses but there could be an issue with how I am getting the data in the first place that is causing this mess.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you have 2 options:

First one simply by using *ngIf, the other one would be to predefine the class within your constructor.

E.g:

```
export interface SkillSets {
    SkillSetID: number;
    SkillSetName: string;
    constructor() {
      this.SkillSetID = 0;
      this.SkillSetName = "Yet undefined";
    }
}
```

Inside your component e.g in the constructor:

```
this.skillSets = new SkillSets();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the async pipe, set your skillSets like this

```
  skillSets = this._massEmpService.transitionFields();
```

Note that you don't need the subscribe method. That is the benefit of using the async pipe and make your code shorter.
And in your template.

```
  <option *ngFor="let s of skillSets | async" value="{{ s.SkillSetID }}">
  {{ s.SkillSetName }}</option>
```

Lastly, update your skillSet data type like this

```
skillSets: Observable<SkillSets[]>;
```

because you are now dealing with observables and not just a normal array.

Note that if you are having a problem, try to set the skillSets in your constructor or OnInit, call the fetchFieldData() from there.

**Update 1**

Since you provide lots of new code from your updates, here's my updated answer.

If you use async pipe, you don't need this code

this.segments = results.segments.options;

This is how you get the options data from your service. Your concern is that you get the whole data and you just need the 'option' data. You need to change the way you return data in your service. Change it to this

```
return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + '/fetchTransitionFields', { "effectiveStartDate": effectiveStartDate }, { "headers": this.headers })
        .map((result: Response) => result.json().segments.options)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can I still use this even though my subscribe is on a `BehaviorSubject`? I started changing the code to reflect yours and it gave me some problems regarding that.

Comment: @SBB of course you can still use it. What are the problems?

Comment: When I removed the subscribe and replaced it with the first line. `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'BehaviorSubject<any>' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @SBB try to remove the subscribe method in your transitionFields() and let me know if it works

Comment: The error went away but with the code above, its assigning the full object of data to `skillSets` instead of just the array I need for that dropdown. Once I get this fixed, I will have several drop downs that are all typed to interfaces.

Comment: Ah I see. What you are trying to achieve is bigger than your real question. You probably need to post another question regarding this.

Comment: @SBB Based from the template you provided, yes it will display all the skillSets. You probably need to change your code though if you want to have your dropdowns to have their own data

Comment: The thing is, I had all this working. I stored the whole object retrieved from the service and then each of my select inputs looped over their respected arrays in the object. The issue is that I wasn't able to type each of the arrays since I was assigning the whole object and not each of them individually.

Comment: @SBB can you log the data with the whole object?

Comment: I updated the question that shows more of the code being used to see how it have it set up currently.

Comment: I really appreciate your back and forth help on this. While this looks promising, I am going to see if there is a solution that will allow me to only have to make one service call to get the full object and then `type` them to their  own individual objects within the component so I can use `ngFor` on them to display them. Your suggestion will work fine if I had the one array I needed but I would need to duplicate that about 10 times which is a little unnecessary if I can do it in one.